# How to work with AndroidManifest and Assembly

Tags: xamarin.android

Base on Xamarin Studio instruction, I follow it to create the AndroidManifest which looks as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="1.0" 
package="HelloMultiScreen.HelloMultiScreen">

    <uses-sdk />

    <application android:label="HelloMultiScreen">
<application>


<manifest>
```

I have these questions:

1) How come it DOES NOT list out all the control or widget like the google manifest?
2) Do I need to edit it whenever I add additional control or widget like textView ? 
3) Do I need to care about the order of the control or widget of which I add first or later?

4) Do I need to manually add the below or it is self generated?

[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
 [assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of your questions are answered in this page - http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml

In general, Xamarin auto-generates much of the file for you, using hints in the code like `[Activity]` attributes.

I recommend you read that document above, experiment a little and then come back here if you have specific questions/problems.